# Query More than one relationship from a model with() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need help to query a model base on its relationship:

I have a model called `StoreStock`, this model is related to a `Product` model, which has two model relationships, `MasterList` and `Price`.

I want to get all `storeStock` with two Product relationships.

I know i can do something like

```
StoreStock::all()->with('product.price')
->get()
```

With this, i can only pick either price or masterlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `array` of relationship to `with` method

```
 StoreStock::with(['product.price','product.masterlist']) ->get()
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

A little bit explanation here, many of the Laravel methods which support string, also support arrays. You can hover over the specific method and get the intellisense. In your case, it can be written like:

```php
StoreStock::with(['product.price','product.masterlist'])->get()
```

If you want to run a specific action over any specific relation, you can also write it like this:

```
StoreStock::with(['product.price' => function(Builder $query) {
      // your action required with the query
},'product.masterlist']) ->get()
```

Hope someone finds this helpful